# Swift, NSCoding - uninitialized immutable array object error - custom objects

Tags: swift, nscoding

I'm trying to save my objects using `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. My objects have references to other objects and I encounter a problem when trying to unarchive.

[Objects graph with references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMe32.png)

When all objects are saved, I try to unarchive at GameStore using

```
init() {
        if let archivedPlayers = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: playersArchiveURL.path) as? [Player] {
            allPlayers = archivedPlayers
        }
    }
```

And I get error saying `method sent to an uninitialized immutable array object`.

I discovered that when I delete one part of `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` inside of Player class, I do not get the error any more.

Here is the function with the part that causes problems commented out.

```
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        name = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "name") as! String
        lastTimePlayed = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "lastTimePlayed") as? Date
        timesPlayed = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "timesPlayed")
        playerID = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "playerID") as! String

//        gamesPlayed = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "gamesPlayed") as! [Game]
//        matchesPlayed = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "matchesPlayed") as! [Game : [Match]]
//        gamesPlace = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "gamesPlace") as! [Game : [Int]]
//        gamesPoints = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "gamesPoints") as! [Game : [Int]]
        super.init()
    }
```

Why do I get this error? I was thinking about using gameID and matchID in order to avoid this, but I wonder if there is any better way of handling this problem.

You can look at latest working version (without saving enabled) at my github https://github.com/Przeszaf/BoardGamesTracker.

Comment: How is `allPlayers` declared?

Comment: It is declared inside PlayerStore as     var allPlayers = [Player]()